# calculate height of paragraph with respect to content [data] in it (number of characters)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

paragraph is having fixed width of `300px`
and

```
font-size:20px;
line-height:1.4`
overflow:hidden
```

I want to find out total height that will be occupied 
by paragraph in the UI from the data we have (`number of character` , `font-size` ,`line-height` ,`width:300px`)

Comment: using jquery height you can find like this $('p.classname').height()

Comment: good try but please read question carefully...i want height w.r.t content in paragrah (number of characters)

Comment: use `.text().length`

Comment: If you want number of character in paragraph ,then you can use $('p').text().length

Comment: i want height  :-)
try how to find out height using length of text

Comment: @shank please check snippet

Answer (score 0):

use `.height()`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
alert("height  => " + $("p").height());
 alert("innerHeight => " + $('p').innerHeight());
})
```

```css
p{
  font-size:20px;
line-height:1.4`;
overflow:hidden;
  width:300px;
    background-color:red;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>ABC  xyz ABC XYZ ABC XYZ ABC  xyz ABC XYZ ABC XYZ</p>
```

Comment: dear parth...i dont want height of element...i want height of content in an element...dont make me repeat again n again

Comment: @shank  Both are getting same value. what is problem now? if you have any `padding` or something then it makes diffrence between text height and `p` `height`

Comment: @shank please check i have added padding and you can see difference in height for `.height()` and `innerHeight()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use ineerHeight or height as per you requirement

```
$('p').innerHeight();
$('p').height();
```

Comment: i dont want height of element...i want height of content in an element...please read the question carefully